# Streaming json data with django

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-channels

After serch and research I dont find any way to make realtime HTTP comunication as RTP or like, specifically in python with django and jquery.

Actually my concept the “realtime” is a loop SetInterval that makes a request every 1 second to the http server, django catching the request and process them after return a json response and one on my javascript fuction draw the data in a svg.

Any one can you help me with other solution or best practice?

Thank you!

Comment: real time can be done using sockets

Answer (score 1):

Yes there's a real time communication project actively developing in under Django. It's called Channels.

From Django Channels

> Channels is a project to make Django able to handle more than just plain HTTP requests, including WebSockets and HTTP2,

`Channels`

Comment: Many thanks for your help Raja, I will read the documentation and anything I will notify.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) which is used for real time apps.